# How do I use lambdas with arguments to collect an array?

Tags: ruby, lambda, mapping, block, proc

I was curious how I may refactor this code:

```
array.collect{|x| x.some_method}.inject(:+) || 0
```

I have it about ten times in my code with different methods so I thought I should refactor, but how?

I tried at least ten varieties of blocks, procs and lambdas and at this point I'm not even sure that it can be refactored.

Comment: Consider replacing various parts with something "named" such as `sum` .. names are good. Names create implicit documentation. If the *same line* is repeated multiple times, then that is likely a good candidate to "name" as well.

Comment: "refactor" type questions probably belong on http://codereview.stackexchange.com. See [the CodeReview FAQ](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/faq#questions) for more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refactor how/to what? What's the goal? Do you want/need to go beyond:

```
array.collect(&:some_method).inject(:+) || 0
```

If the only thing that changes is the method being called, pass the method symbol in to a method and send it to each object during collection.

What are you trying to communicate with the code in question? Looks like some sort of summation; perhaps a simple `sum` method with the "property" name as a parameter?

Comment: +1 for suggesting using a name. I'm not sure I'd follow it through to the extracting the property name, though: `sum people.map(&:age)` or similar looks pretty good to me.

Comment: The goal was to get rid of this middle part and i wrapped in a clear named function

Answer (score 1):

First refactor:

```
array.collect(&:some_method).inject(0, :+)
```

Second refactor, abstract:

```
module Enumerable
  def sum(method)
    block_given? ? inject(0) { |acc, x| acc + yield(x) } : inject(0, :+)
  end
end

array.map(&:some_method).sum
array.sum(&:some_method)
```

Answer (score 0):

A Ruby idiom is to use:

```
array.collect(&:some_method).inject(:+)
```

in uses the Symbol#to_proc method: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Symbol.html#method-i-to_proc

Answer (score 0):

You use `array.collect(&:some_method).inject(:+)` for starters. You could also do it with one `inject` call like so:

```
def my_method(ary, method_symbol)
  ary.inject (0) do |sum, elem|
    sum + elem.send( method_symbol )
  end
end
```